# Rigify and Weight Painting

Tags: weight-painting, grease-pencil, rigify

I just made a mouth rig, and used weight painting and Rigify.

[image: screenshot]

I was following a tutorial but structured the mouth to be open on one side instead of a closed circle.  When I applied the weight painting and tried to move the control bones, everything becomes distorted.  Is there something I can use instead of weight painting or how do I fix what I made with weight painting?  I'll try to figure out how to post a file here.

Comment: It is a 2.7 mb file and it is taking a long time to upload.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1Bts4A-9Od0hF-iwGFvc9CKR1_ULF6CUV    Hopefully this works.

Comment: A few screenshots, the link to the tutorial, and details on how you build the rig would help. I guess the right side (character's left side) is the problem?

Comment: https://youtu.be/UTlchZhyS18  Here is the link to the tutorial.  Also, I used weight painting and rigify to make the rig.  Yeah, the left side, the side with the teeth is the problem.